# Where to place the link to the password changing form?

Tags: password

Sorry for this pretty general question... but, where do you place the link for password changing in your websites?, where do you think is the best place? in the login form, in the personal data section, in the header?

Comment: For changing the password, or recovering it? (ie. Why would you ever provide a *change* password link right by a login form?)

Comment: For changing it, I've seen a link like this in the login form in some webs, it asks you for your current pass anyway, being logged or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All applications I worked for, we place link to change password in user profile page (if you have user profile page).

In other case, you can put the link in "Preferences page".